Left mousebutton stuck on pressed state
I have a big problem with KVM and need help. Left mouse is locked. Most of the time it is seen as pressed down in VM.
Background
I work as developer for my living. I have a modern laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 and KVM installed. I have several VMs in KVM all is using Windows 10. This setup started when 24.04 was rather new and it has worked decent well.
The last weeks I had vacation and I have only used laptop for browsing. And also update when Ubuntu prompt me with that.
Today it was my first workday and it was near impossible to do anyting in Windows VM. It sees left mousebutton down all the time.
To determine if error was in Windows or Linux I add a new VM with Ubuntu. And got exact same problem there.
Mouse works fine in Ubuntu on host. So that should mean error is somewhere in KVM ?
But I am lost, I cannot work anymore. I suspect some of the recent updates I did during vacation.
How can I revert those updates? Anything more I can do ?
What community should continue to ask about this KVM/Qemu problem ?
I shared a video how it look like on desktop. Note that I don't press any mousebuttons. I just move the mouse around.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V06Yor1iWG0UoTp8LXL-hIbS0Oqzm8eR/view?usp=sharing

Defective hardware would act the same. Install new VM same issue. No one can help you reverse an install if you do not say what was installed. No one here is going to know what an update did on your computer.

Now it is even more strange. I took my laptop to office. And everything work as expected. Now I really hope it works when back at home...
